# Eclipse "Create Web Service" Showing Weird Error

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, json, wsdl

EDIT 2:

I probably should have mentioned this earlier, but I'm getting a warning after I set up the Web Service (but before it is actually made, where the error occurs). Here is the warning:

> The service class
>   "net.rim.Indy.WebService.Functions_JSONP"
>   does not comply to one or more
>   requirements of the JAX-RPC 1.1
>   specification, and may not deploy or
>   function correctly.

And the juice:

> The service class
>   "net.rim.Indy.WebService.Functions_JSONP"
>   does not comply to one or more
>   requirements of the JAX-RPC 1.1
>   specification, and may not deploy or
>   function correctly.   The field or
>   property "cause" on the value type
>   "atg.taglib.json.util.JSONException"
>   used via the service class
>   "net.rim.Indy.WebService.Functions_JSONP"
>   has a data type,
>   "java.lang.Throwable", that is not
>   supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1
>   specification. Instances of the type
>   may not serialize or deserialize
>   correctly. Loss of data or complete
>   failure of the Web service may result.

If this is fixed, I have a feeling the Web Service will start working, because it is identical to another one I have except for the JSON functionality. Something needs to be changed so that my web service is fully supported by the JAX specs.

EDIT:

I'm now getting around the issue where it is automatically choosing the wrong project for me. I followed **File->New->Web Service**. My settings are as follows:

```
Web service type: Bottom up
Service implementation: net.aaa.bbb.WebService.Functions_JSONP
Server runtime: Tomcat v6
Web service runtime: Apache Axis
Service project: ABC
Client type: Java Proxy
```

I check off "Publish the Web service" and hit Next. Then on the next page I hit Next again to generate Functions_JSONP.wsdl and get the following error:

```
IWAB0398E Error in generating WSDL from Java:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.aaa.bbb.WebService.Functions_JSONP
```

Here is the full stack trace:

```
IWAB0398E Error in generating WSDL from Java:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.aaa.bbb.WebService.Functions_JSONP
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.aaa.bbb.WebService.Functions_JSONP
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:204)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:100)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.fromJava.Emitter.setCls(Emitter.java:2079)
    at org.apache.axis.tools.ant.wsdl.Java2WsdlAntTask.execute(Java2WsdlAntTask.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.axis.consumption.core.command.Java2WSDLCommand.executeAntTask(Java2WSDLCommand.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.axis.consumption.core.command.Java2WSDLCommand.execute(Java2WSDLCommand.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.axis.creation.ui.command.BUCodeGenOperation$BottomUpWSModifyOperation.execute(BUCodeGenOperation.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.axis.creation.ui.command.BUCodeGenOperation.execute(BUCodeGenOperation.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.runCommand(CommandFragmentEngine.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.visitTop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.moveForwardToNextStop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager$6.run(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1008)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager.runForwardToNextStop(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.runForwardToNextStop(WizardPageManager.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.getNextPage(WizardPageManager.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleWizardPage.getNextPage(SimpleWizardPage.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:887)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
```

What could be the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: what is your eclipse version? Is the project where you right-click .java file a regular java project or a web project?

Comment: java web project. i've updated my question with my progress but i was stuck there yesterday =S any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your message it looks like a serialization problem. You seem to be exposing a throwable class as part of the public api and this is in violation with JAX-RPC. (Please check your exception classes for instances of throwable. Remove them and you should be fine).

Note: Example of occurrence. If your exception has this, then its a violation.

private Throwable throwable;

public Throwable getThrowable() {
        return throwable;
    }